# Calculating accuracy of a predicted value

Tags: statistics, neural-network, classification, prediction

I have a multi-layer neural network based estimator that takes inputs the past arrival times of vehicles and estimates the arrival time of next vehicle (with a backpropagation algorithm). Based on a certain threshold (e.g, 10sec), the estimator classifies the predicted time to be high or low (1 or 0). My problem is that, based on the observed and predicted/estimated arrival times (1's & 0's), how do I calculate the accuracy (or the correct prediction rate) of the overall prediction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to define for yourself what you mean with `high (1)` and `low (0)`. For example, you could say that `high` arrival time equals 5 minutes or more, and `low` arrival time as less than 5 minutes. Once your neural network gives a prediction, then you can check in your samples whether the next car's arrival time is indeed `high` or `low` (i.e., respectively more than 5 minutes or less than 5 minutes). You can calculate the accuracy of your prediction using this.

Comment: This is what I am doing as I described in the question. High (1) means a period less than 10 seconds and Low (0) means a period greater than 10 seconds. I do check the predicted value with the observed value. Therefore, I have 4 sets of values, i.e., Low|predicted, High|predicted, Low|observed, High|observed. The question is how do I calculate the accuracy of the prediction algorithm.

Comment: Aah I missed that! You can calculate the accuracy as follows: if the `predicted` value matches the `observed` value, then do `correct_count += 1`. Once you're finished you find the accuracy by dividing the `correct_count` with the total amount of predictions you made: `correct_count / total_predictions_amount`